# Kubernetes readinessProbe configure to change pinging time

Tags: kubernetes, readinessprobe

My setting for readinessProbe is following:

```
readinessProbe:
            httpGet:
              path: /up
              port: *status-port
            initialDelaySeconds: 5
            periodSeconds: 5
            successThreshold: 1
```

I want to change the `periodSeconds` to a larger value once my pod is running ok. Is it possible to achieve this? Since during starting of the pod it makes sense to probe it once every 5 seconds, but once it is running fine, it would be more efficient use of resource to probe it once every say 30 seconds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Such a feature doesn't exist. You can look [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-liveness-readiness-probes/#configure-probes) for available options.